# Where is the Sculpt mirror in 2.8?

Tags: sculpting

2.8 is supposed to be easier?  I can't find anything and the hotkeys don't work.

I'm trying to sculpt with symmetry but I can't find the X mirror.  In the old versions of blender, this is suppose to be on by default...

Wouldn't it make sense to have it as on of the many buttons on the left?  Geez.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: symmetry options]

Also, the side "N" panel has a symmetry section.

Comment: 2.8 is definitely more cryptic than the previous versions.  I can't find anything but thanks for your help!